# Group Of Even Number Has Odd Number Of Elements Of Order 2

Tags: group-theory, proof-explanation, solution-verification

This question was asked many times in the past, I just want to be sure I got the answer correctly.

We take a group $G$ which has an even order, we take all the elements of order greater then $2$ and pair them with their inverses (of the same order of course) we get a set (it maybe not a subgroup) of an even order let say $A$, then $|G|-|A|$ is even, now we are left with elements of order $1$ which is $e$ and elements of order $2$.

Then we have $|G|-|A|-\{e\}=2k-1$ then the number of elements of order $2$ is odd

Comment: It is indeed a correct way to prove it. An equivalent way is to interpret $x\mapsto x^{-1}$ as a permutation of order $2$ and decompose into a product of transpositions, which amounts to the same thing in the end.

Answer (score 1):

Your argument is completely right. Let me point out that the proof is very much alike to that of a well-known [theorem](https://proofwiki.org/wiki/Center_of_Group_of_Prime_Power_Order_is_Non-Trivial): a non-trivial finite group $G$ of prime power order has a non-trivial center $Z(G)$. Recall that the key ingredient of the proof is [the class equation](https://proofwiki.org/wiki/Conjugacy_Class_Equation) (or [the partition equation](https://proofwiki.org/wiki/Partition_Equation))
$$ G = \coprod_{g \in [G/\sim_G]} g^G = 1^G \amalg \left(Z(G) \setminus 1^G\right) \amalg \coprod_{\substack{g \in [G/\sim_G]\\ g \not\in Z(G)}} g^G.$$

Now, in your setting, let's consider a group $T = \langle t \rangle$ of order two and acts on the group $G$ of even order by $g^t = g^{-1}$. Then you have $T$-orbit decomposition
$$ G = \coprod_{g \in [G/\sim_T]} g^T = 1^T \amalg \left(I(G) \setminus 1^T\right) \amalg \coprod_{\substack{g \in [G/\sim_T]\\ g \not\in I(G)}} g^T, $$
where $ I(G) = \{\, g \in G \mid g^2 = 1 \,\} $. Taking cardinality, you'll get the conclusion.

You may find several others that fit into this scheme.